# Unterschied zwischen Gesicht und Angesicht

Tags: difference, meaning, noun

Was ist der Unterschied zwischen den beiden Wörtern *Gesicht* und *Angesicht*? Der [Duden](http://www.duden.de/rechtschreibung/Angesicht) sagt zu Angesicht, dass dies in der gehobenen Sprache gebraucht wird. Ist dies die einzige Differenzierung? Wann verwendet man welches Wort?

Beispiele:

> Er spuckte ihr ins Gesicht.
>
> Er spuckte ihr ins Angesicht.

(Hinweis: ich meine *Gesicht* in der Bedeutung [1.a im Duden](http://www.duden.de/rechtschreibung/Gesicht_Aussehen_Miene_Sinn).)

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Ich würde sagen, dass sich „Gesicht“ mehr auf das physische Gesicht als Teil des Kopfs bezieht, während „Angesicht” häufig mehr eine Metabedeutung bekommt und sich auf die Person als Ganzes bezieht.

Beispielsweise würde „im Angesicht von jmd.” bedeuten, dass es im *Beisein* der Person passiert. Oder dass man etwas direkt *vor den Augen* desjenigen macht. Somit bekommt das noch einmal eine andere Wirkung.

Daher würde ich den Beispielsatz aus der Frage („ins Angesicht spucken”) so auch niemals nutzen.

Comment: "ins Angesicht spucken" würde aber vielleicht die damit einhergehende Beleidigung und Verletzung der Persönlichkeit deutlich machen, oder? :-)

Comment: Ja, schon, aber dann würde ich das eher bildlich verstehen.

Answer (score 4):

Im modernen Deutsch hat sich *Angesicht* zu *Gesicht* reduziert. Die Verwendung der alten Form wird nur noch poetisch verwendet.

Man findet es nur noch in feststehenden Phrasen wie „angesichts der Tatsache …“ wieder.

Der Ursprung ist wohl durch das Wort *ansehen* begründet.

Comment: Ist "vor dem Angesicht" auch eine solche Phrase? Beispielsatz: "Er klaute das Auto vor dem Angesicht des Besitzers."

Comment: @jor: Ja. Es klingt auch etwas theatralisch.

Comment: Ich finde das eine sehr komische Ausdrucksweise.

Comment: Ich glaube, es wäre auch viel mehr:
Er klaute das Auto im Angesicht des Besitzers oder?